# Imaginary bases lead to complex entropy. Is complex entropy useful in quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I'm working through the Programming Drill 10.2.1 from Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists. I am not a student; this is not homework. I'm just doing this for my own betterment.

I notice that keeping the basis real and orthogonal means that the density matrix is zero outside of the diagonal, and that the entries for the diagonal are the eigenvalues.

If it's not orthogonal, then the density matrix is generally non-zero outside of the diagonal, and the entries for the diagonal are generally not the eigenvalues.

If it's imaginary, then the entropy becomes complex.

***Are imaginary bases used in quantum computing? I know that messages need not be orthogonal, but imaginary? How does one interpret such a thing? What is complex entropy?***

The code is below. The code is also part of a repository -- https://github.com/sjhalayka/qc_for_cs

The code requires the Eigen header-only library -- https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/

Thanks for your time and expertise!

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

#include "Eigen/Dense"
using Eigen::VectorXcf;
using Eigen::MatrixXcf;

#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
using Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver;


int main(void)
{
    // The width and height of the density matrix depends on the 
    // number of orthogonal bases n. The number of eigenvalues and
    // eigenvectors are both n as well.
    // 
    // Here we will use a distinct base for each message
    // simply because we can do so

    const size_t n = 4;

    // Initialize orthogonal bases
    vector<VectorXcf> orthogonal_bases(n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        VectorXcf base(n);

        // Note:
        // Keeping things real and orthogonal means that the
        // density matrix is zero outside of the diagonal,
        // and that the entries for the diagonal are the
        // eigenvalues
        //
        // If it's not orthogonal, then the density matrix
        // is generally non-zero outside of the diagonal, 
        // and the entries for the diagonal are not the eigenvalues
        //
        // If it's imaginary, then the entropy becomes complex

        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
                base(j) = complex<float>(1, 0);
            else
                base(j) = complex<float>(0, 0);
        }

        orthogonal_bases[i] = base;
    }


    // Intialize messages
    vector<VectorXcf> messages(n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        messages[i] = orthogonal_bases[i];


    // Get probabilities
    // Spice things up with a pseudorandom PDF
    // Use Mersenne Twister for the pseudorandom number generator
    vector<float> probabilities(n);

    mt19937 mt;
    mt.seed(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    float grand_total = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        probabilities[i] = static_cast<float>(mt() % 256 + 1); // Larger than zero
        grand_total += probabilities[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        probabilities[i] /= grand_total;


    // Calculate density matrix
    // See equation 10.14
    MatrixXcf density_matrix(n, n);
    density_matrix.setZero(); // IMPORTANT

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        density_matrix += probabilities[i] * messages[i] * messages[i].transpose();

    cout << "Density matrix =" << endl << density_matrix << endl << endl;


    // For getting eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    const ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcf> ces(density_matrix);


    // Calculate von Neumann entropy
    complex<float> entropy = 0;

    cout << "Eigenvalues are: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ces.eigenvalues().rows(); i++)
    {
        const complex<float> p = ces.eigenvalues().row(i).col(0)(0);
        
        cout << p << endl;
        
        entropy += p * log(1.0f/p);
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "von Neumann entropy is: " << entropy / logf(2.0f) << endl << endl;


    cout << "Eigenvectors are: " << endl;

    vector<vector<complex<float>>> bases;

    for (int i = 0; i < ces.eigenvectors().rows(); i++)
    {
        vector<complex<float>> base;

        for (int j = 0; j < ces.eigenvectors().row(i).cols(); j++)
            base.push_back(ces.eigenvectors().row(i).col(j)(0));

        bases.push_back(base);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bases.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < bases[i].size(); j++)
            cout << bases[i][j] << ' ';

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Density matrices, by construction, have positive eigenvalues that sum to 1. My guess is that you have made a generic matrix but have not restricted it to be a positive matrix (ie one with positive eigenvalues). It is certainly possible for the density matrix to have complex entries on the off-diagonals, all you need is a positive (and Hermitian) matrix, so the basis states could certainly be complex but you'll still get a positive [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) $$S(\rho)=-\mathrm{Tr}(\rho\ln \rho)=-\sum_n p_n \ln p_n \geq 0$$ where $\{p_n\}$ are the eigenvalues of $\rho$ and $\rho \succeq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I noticed that the non-diagonal entries of the matrix are non-zero where the bases are not orthogonal, and that the diagonal entries are not necessarily the eigenvalues. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @shawn_halayka that is correct, I recommend learning a bit more about eigenvalues and eigenvectors and these things will become easier. The first nice property about diagonal entries is that they are the eigenvalues in the case where the rest of the matrix is 0; the second nice properties is that the sum of the diagonal elements is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues for any matrix (that is known as the trace)

Comment: thank you so much for the insight!